Understanding measure of supremum of finite sums
*Note this is not a duplicate but rather a short question surrounding an older post
I have a question about this post.
I understand the provided proof and had considered something similar. But, how $\mu$ is defined in this post drastically simplifies it and I didn’t understand the following part of the definition:

$$\sum_{x\in A} \alpha_{x} = \sup_{F \subset A \text{ finite}} \sum_{x \in F} \alpha_{x}$$

This seems quite intuitive. My question is whether this is generally the case and if so why? Any help is appreciated.

Given that $\alpha_x \ge 0$ for all $x$ (note that in the other post $\alpha$ has codomain $[0,\infty]$), this is the definition of the left-hand side when $A$ is infinite. Note that $A$ has no built-in well-ordering that you could use to define it like a series on $\Bbb N$. And since the sum of a series under rearrangement does not change if and only if the series is absolutely convergent, we usually only define infinite summation over general sets when the summand is non-negative. Otherwise, the limit might not be unique.
